# Get tile position on which dragged sprite present

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Please help me i am stuck at:

I am moving an sprite by - (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

on tile map of 40X30 tile size i want to get tile position on which my sprite is currently stopped and set that sprite on that tile, like words smith game.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TILES_X` and `TILES_Y` are the number of horizontal and vertical tiles on your map, something like this should do the trick:

edit: added `TILE_WIDTH` & `TILE_HEIGHT` to correct position calculation

```
CGPoint position = [sprite position];

// get x and y in tile coordinates
int xTile = position.x / TILES_X;
int yTile = position.y / TILES_Y;

// 'snap' position to tiles
position.x = xTile * TILE_WIDTH;
position.y = yTile * TILE_HEIGHT;
[sprite setPosition:position];
```

Comment: I am adding this code but i can not place the sprite on exact tile position

Comment: Please Help me , i am stuck over it.

Comment: my tile number are 15 horiontal and 15 vertical, means my map size is of 15X15

Comment: What is happening? Also this code should go in the touches ended event.

Comment: did you see the game wordswithsmith game.., i am developing the same game, i have to move an sprite on tile map and should fix on the exact  tile where it is..

Comment: I forgot to add tile size to the equation. See my edited post.

Comment: CGPoint position = [selSprite position];
    
    // get x and y in tile coordinates
    int xTile = position.x / 15;
    int yTile = position.y / 15;
    
    // 'snap' position to tiles
    position.x = xTile * 15 * 20;
    position.y = yTile * 15 * 15;
    [selSprite setPosition:position];

Comment: This my code to get the position on tile, and i am now getting totally wrong position, position is something out of bound.

Comment: CGPoint position = [selSprite position];
    
    int xTile = position.x / 15;
    int yTile = position.y / 15;
    
    // 'snap' position to tiles
    position.x = xTile * 15 * 20;
    position.y = yTile * 15 * 15;
    [selSprite setPosition:position];

Comment: If you can tell me your emailId i can send you my code,Please have a look on it.

Comment: I fixed the snapping coordinates again, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your kind help, it works, now i can set sprite on tile, but i am getting some problem tile position and collision with image tile is not the same, it is setting on some other tile

Comment: I f you could see, i can send my code to you ,please have a look where i am doing wrong, it will be really helpful..

Comment: Please reply me , i am not getting correct tile where it should be placed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24550/discussion-between-alexander-and-wasif-saood)